Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning Failed to Import IPAM GPOs
I've recently provisioned an IPAM server and the when I try to create the IPAM GPOs with the following:
Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning -Domain Domain.FQDN -GpoPrefixName IPAM -IpamServerFqdn IPAM.Domain.FQDN

The Powershell returned error:
Invoke-IpamGpoProvisioning : Failed to import GPO. The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
At line:1 char:1

I have domain admin access to the domain and I was running Powershell as admin.
Any suggestions?
